# Simple password protection for non-sensitive links

Tags: javascript, html

I’ve been looking at password protection for HTML and most of the protection listed appears to be overkill for my needs.

I just want to have some portfolio images (nothing that needs to be private and it doesn’t matter if any advanced programmer or someone that knows how to open the code can get into it because nothing is sensitive),  I just don’t want the average user to access certain areas of site and only allow someone who I give the password (for example on my business card.)

Does anyone have any suggestions or direction I should look?

Comment: Give examples of what you've seen that would be overkill. There are fairly simple implementations you could use.

Comment: There is no such thing as "password protection for HTML." HTML is just a language for rendering content in a browser. Are you running a server of any sort? What do you mean by "have some portfolio images," and where?

Comment: If you only need that minimal level of security by obscurity (i.e. a public but slightly-hidden location) then why not just put the images on a URL that you only give out to those who need it? Don't link to the URL from anywhere and use `robots.txt` to prevent any indexing.

Comment: Many web hosting companies offer a way to protect folders just using your admin console without having to get too dirty.  Check your hosting first and see if they give you that option.

Comment: My gut feel is that you should be looking at the web server rather than the pages. What web server are you using?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice and will look into it when my technical level becomes more advanced. But just looking for something that makes future employers (very HTML naieve people) think they are in a secure area. Will look at the robots.txt though because from my understanding you could probably link into the page avoiding the simple password.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use javascript in your main page, something like this:

```
<body>
Enter password: <input id='password' type='text'  />
<a href="your_image_portfolio.html" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">enter your password and click this</a>
<script>
function validatePass(){
    if(document.getElementById('password').value == 'yourBussinessCardPassword'){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert('wrong password!!');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

It's very insecure, but it will do what you want for non technical users...

Comment: Yes this is appropriate for my level and is good enough to stop the users I expect to be mulling around my site ... Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to hash "yourBussinessCardPassword" ahead of time and compare to that so that you don't have to reveal the password and anyone who could view the source still wouldn't be able to login?

Comment: @ScottBeeson sure, but anyone with knowledge to open the function will be able to modify it to always return true, so it will add no security. This 'solution' remains just as a simple, fast ans NON SECURE way to protect simple content

Answer (score 0):

As said above, HTML doesn't support password protection directly. You can do this with PHP: create a form to enter a password that sends data to a PHP script. Use an if statement at the beginning of the PHP script that checs whether the submitted data matches your password. If it doesn't, redirect/include some sort of error page. If it does, have it load the rest of the gallery from inside the if statement.

```
<?php

if ($_POST["password"] == 12345) {
page goes here
}
else {
include 'errorpage'
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

    function Sinfo()
    {

        var info = document.getElementById("info").value; //Getting the value in the Text Area
        var help = "Hello"; // setting the value for the password 

            if(info==help){ // checking to see if info is equal to help

            document.write("Correct Password"); // writing correct password if correct


    }
        else{

        document.write("Wrong Password"); // writing the wrong password if wrong

        }

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: A good answer is usually accompanied by an explanation, you can always edit your posts!